# Meaning of: void * _Nullable (* _Nonnull)(void * _Nullable)

Tags: c, function

I am passing functions to `pthread_create` function. I am getting a warning that complains about incompatible type of function passed as an argument:

```
void * _Nullable (* _Nonnull)(void * _Nullable)
```

I managed to fix it by declaring my function as:

```
void *incFunc(void *ptr){
    for (long i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i) { counter++;}
    return NULL;
}
```

, but I don't really understand the meaning of expected argument type:

```
void * _Nullable (* _Nonnull)(void * _Nullable)
```

- void * _Nullable == the return type of the function should be pointer to void
- (void * _Nullable) == accepted parameter is pointer to void
- **(* _Nonnull) ???? This is the one I don't understand this**

What does `(* _Nonnull)` represent?

Comment: Probably some compiler extension to cause warnings if you attempt to pass a null pointer there.

Comment: You probably want to tag the question with `objective-c`

Comment: I am on osx indeed, but warnings are of C code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means:

it has to be not NULL function pointer taking `void *` parameter which can be NULL and returning `void *`. The return value can be NULL.